# Setting the font of the individual option in a drop-down menu?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to set the font-family for each option in a drop down list? If so, how is it done?

EDIT: Specifically, I'd like to see this work in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser support is variable.

```
option.aClass /* or some other way to identify the specific option */ {
    font-family: times, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a class to each option and style it ..

**html**

```
<select>
    <option class="c1">this option has c1</option>
    <option class="c2">this option has c2</option>
</select>
```

**Css**

```
.c1 {font-family:courier;color:red}
.c2 {font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;;color:blue;}
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/xdXFz/

---

It works only in FF (*from my tests*), all other browsers (*IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera*) only take into consideration the color..

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a `class` attribute to each `<option>`, however this isn't suported by <strike>most</strike> a lot of user agents. I would investigate some fancy JQuery / framework solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it's better to create your own drop-down list than to style these types of controls.

Comment: You could use `<ul><li></li></ul>` to create the list structure with different styles on every <li> item and then use simple javavscript to show the list and interact with it (using jQuery in this case would make it easy).

Comment: Here is an example: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jaimedelpalacio/archive/2008/11/22/custom-html-dropdown-control-part-1.aspx)